# Rotate Tag Buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to rotate few buttons in my programing and I know  that I can use `Button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);`

But the point here is if I use this code, all my buttons will rotate because I used one `UIButton` for all, but they have tags. How can I rotate each of them individually by using their tag numbers? or any other idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "one UIButton for all"? Will be better if you share buttons creation code.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, which is a bit unclear. You have a class which is the button class. If you want you can extends this class you can add the rotating behaviour on that class.

To be more helpful you need to update your question with additional data or concrete code.